# How to put a React-Icons into innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to put a React-Icons into innerHTML of element whenever I clicked it.

like this: `target.innerHTML = '<ImCross/>';`

But it always failed to show the icons. BUT It will work perfectly if I'm using another element like `<span></span>` and just put some **letters** in it. So, is there a way to put an Icon into InnerHtml?

This is the example of my code:

```
import { ImCross } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-icons/im";

const App = () => {
  const box = {
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    width: 150,
    height: 140
  }
  
  const symbol = {
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    position: 'relative',
    top: 30,
    fontSize: 70
  }
  
  const handleClickedBox = (e) => {
    const target = e.currentTarget.querySelector('.symbol');
    
    // THIS IS FAILED TO SHOW THE ICON
    target.innerHTML = '<ImCross/>';
    
    // THIS DOESN'T WORK TOO
    target.innerHTML = '<span> <ImCross/> </span>';    

    // BUT THIS ONE IS WORK
    target.innerHTML = '<span>X</span>';
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {/* This is the box that will be clicked */}
      <div onClick={(e) => handleClickedBox(e)} style={box}>
        {/* This is element that it's innerHTML will show the symbol */}
        <div className='symbol' style={symbol}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

THIS THE NEW CODE WITH MULTIPLE BOXES:

What it's the best way if it's not with innerHTML to show the icon ONLY in clicked box, like in my code here

```
import { ImCross } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-icons/im";

const App = () => { 
  const boxes = {
      backgroundColor: '#000',
      color: '#fff',
      width: 120,
      height: 120,
    }
   
  const symbol = {
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 50
  }
  
   const styles = {
      display: 'grid',
      gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3, 120px)',
      gap: 10
    }
    
    const handleClickBoard = (e) => {
      // Here, I'm gettin <div> of clicked box
      const clickedBox = e.currentTarget;
      
      // What should i do here to make the children 
         element of clicked element/box show the icon <ImCross />
      
      // I only can achieve what I want by using this
      clickedBox.querySelector('.symbol-on-board').innerHTML = 'X';
    }
   
    let component = [];
    let key = 0;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            key++;
            component.push(
                {/* This the BOX that wrap the symbol */}
                <div style={boxes} id={key} key={key} onClick={(e) => handleClickBoard(e)}>
                {/* This is where i want the symbol to be shown */}
                    <div style={symbol} className='symbol-on-board'></div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
  
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        {component}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Don't try to manipulate the DOM directly when using a framework that expects to have complete control of the DOM.

Comment: @DanielBeck can you give me solution with the new code that I just added?

Comment: Your new code is basically the same as your own code, you're still bypassing just about everything that makes React worth using. I can't really improve on @Quentin's answer below; if it's not clear to you (which is reasonable! React takes a big shift in thinking!) I'd suggest going through some tutorials to get more comfortable with the way it's intended to work.

Answer (score 3):

JSX is not HTML. It gets transformed into a bunch of JavaScript calls by Babel before it goes near the browser.

Don't try to generate React code dynamically. Work *with* React. Make use of the features it provides, like state.

For example:

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

const clickHandler = () => { setClicked(current => !current); }

return (
    <div>
        <div onClick={clickHandler} style={box}>
            <div className='symbol' style={symbol}>
                {clicked ? <ImCross/> : "Not clicked yet" }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

---

Re comment: A more complex example with multiple boxes.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
    { name: "Alice", clicked: false },
    { name: "Bob", clicked: false },
    { name: "Chuck", clicked: false }
]);

return <div>{
    data.map(person => 
        <Person key={person.name} setData={setData} person={person} />
    )
}</div>;
```

and then

```
const Person = ({setData, person}) => {
    const clickHandler = () => {
        setData(data => {
            return data.map(item => {
                if (item.name === person.name) {
                    return {
                       ...person,
                       clicked: !person.clicked
                    };
                }
                return person;
            })
        });
    }
    return <div onClick={clickHandler}>
        {person.clicked && <ImCross/>}
        {person.name}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: But what if I worked with a lot of box that can be click? If I'm using state like your example above, it will show the Icon to all the box, right? While what I want is, it will only show in the clicked box. That's why I'm using `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: No, because if you were doing that (at least in a state as simple as this) you could have a separate component with its own state for each one. In a more complex situation it would be typical to have an array of data which is used to generate the boxes (so each item in the array would make one box be displayed) and your click handler would update the array in the state.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quite understand with the example you gave. But I have add new code with multiple boxes in my own way. Can you please try it,?